# What was my commitment?

Tags: support

When I committed to this StackExchange, I saw a summary of the things I was expected to do: make N posts, answer N questions, upvote N times. I don't remember these exact numbers.

At present, the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500) page says of the 278 committed users, "0% fulfilled commitment." Can I dig deeper for my own account and see what I have not yet completed, or at least what the original commitment was?

**Update 8/19:** Just got an email thanking me for fulfilling my commitment. The Area 51 page now lists >4% fulfilled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find out what the current definition of a commitment is, [the best way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/commitment-what-do-i-need-to-do) is to go to another proposal and click the "Commit!" button. The current text is:

> I commit to participate actively in *the named proposal* for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to **ask or answer at least ten questions**.

This is [intentionally hard to find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59725/where-can-i-follow-my-commitments), since they don't want people to game the system.

You seem to have [asked two questions and answered thirteen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/66) (activity on Meta is not counted), so you have fulfilled your commitment. I believe commitment fulfillments are not counted in the private beta, so the number will start changing in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be at least 4 questions. Among other things.